# undefined references even though .so file has them

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

My C++ Project uses a library in form of header files and one shared object. When I try to build it, I get this:

```
FAILED: insta360 
: && /usr/bin/c++ -g  CMakeFiles/insta360.dir/main.cpp.o -o insta360  /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so && :
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_devnode'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_enable_receiving'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_syspath'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_new_from_netlink'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysname'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_get_list_entry'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_receive_device'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_scan_devices'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_get_fd'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_action'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_name'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_new'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_next'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_new'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_property'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

But when I run `nm -D /usr/lib/libCameraSDK.so | grep udev` I get

```
             U udev_device_get_action
             U udev_device_get_devnode
             U udev_device_get_sysname
             U udev_device_new_from_syspath
             U udev_device_unref
             U udev_enumerate_add_match_property
             U udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem
             U udev_enumerate_get_list_entry
             U udev_enumerate_new
             U udev_enumerate_scan_devices
             U udev_enumerate_unref
             U udev_list_entry_get_name
             U udev_list_entry_get_next
             U udev_monitor_enable_receiving
             U udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype
             U udev_monitor_get_fd
             U udev_monitor_new_from_netlink
             U udev_monitor_receive_device
             U udev_monitor_unref
             U udev_new
             U udev_unref
```

So the functions are present and the .so file is correctly imported. My header files are in `/usr/include` and I have no Idea what could be wrong since I'm not very experienced with setting up C++ Projects myself and have only modified them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `U` means that they are undefined, not that they are present.

Comment: Unless you are using a different `nm` than I am, a **U** means *undefined*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`U` means that the symbol is undefined, not that it is present.

Perhaps you need to link against some other library. Since the functions all start with `udev`, it is reasonable to assume that they belong to some library that deals with this thing called "udev". Maybe, just maybe, that library is called "libudev"?